# problem with inserting data into the bar chart plotly graph_objects

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.graph-objects

so I'm trying to add the lists ( Internal, External ..) to the bar chart but the data goes to one column "internal"

[image: bar chart]

it is supposed to be similar to this

[image: similar to]

here is the whole df and the work I did

[image: whole df]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the problem is:

1. You want to plot a bar chart with `plotly.graph_objects`
2. What exactly is data that `go.Bar()` needed. (`status`, `escalation`)

Deduce from questions above,
a) How do you fetch the minimum portion of data for the demo in Stack Overflow?
b) How to prepare the data from your `df` and transform them available to plot.

Preparing for the data we want to plot:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
random.seed(42)
sample_quntity = 50
status = [random.choice(['Not Done','Something Else','Done']) for i in range(sample_quntity)]
escalation = [random.choice(['Internal','External','Unspecified']) for i in range(sample_quntity)]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'status':status,
    'escalation':escalation
})
df
###
            status   escalation
0             Done  Unspecified
1         Not Done     External
2         Not Done     Internal
3             Done  Unspecified
4   Something Else     External
5         Not Done  Unspecified
⋮                ⋮            ⋮
43  Something Else  Unspecified
44        Not Done  Unspecified
45        Not Done     Internal
46  Something Else     Internal
47        Not Done     External
48  Something Else     External
49  Something Else     External
```

Plot:

```
# plot bar chart grouping with status and escalation and color by status
group_list = df['escalation'].unique()
palette = {"Not Done": "#d89a9e","Something Else":"#e0c1b3", "Done": "#aeb4a9"}

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Not Done',
           x=group_list,
           y=df[df['status'] == 'Not Done'].groupby('escalation').size(),
           marker_color=palette['Not Done']),
    go.Bar(name='Something Else',
           x=group_list,
           y=df[df['status'] == 'Something Else'].groupby('escalation').size(),
           marker_color=palette['Something Else']),
    go.Bar(name='Done',
           x=group_list,
           y=df[df['status'] == 'Done'].groupby('escalation').size(),
           marker_color=palette['Done'])])

fig.update_layout(title='Group by Escalation, Color by Status', barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image]